# How to integrate DynamicC compiler(Rabbit Microcontroller/C ) with the Eclipse IDE

Tags: c, eclipse, integrate, dynamic-c

I would like to integrate the Dynamic C compiler which is compiler for the [RABBIT microcontroller](http://www.digi.com/products/wireless-wired-embedded-solutions/software-microprocessors-accessories/software/dynamicc.jsp#overview) into the Eclipse IDE. I really like eclipse environment and its features.

Is there any method I can use to integrate such external compiler into the Eclipse Environment. Any detailed writeup of howto would be very helpful.

Answer (score 2):

I don't know that compiler, but Eclipse can be configured to use various compilers.

You should create a C project, right-click it and select "Properties".  Then take a look at C/C++ Build -> Settings  and  C/C++ Build -> Tool Chain Editor.

If your compiler is properly installed (i.e. you can build things with it on the command line or through another tool), then you should be able to get the right things set in the "C/C++ Build" options.

Here's the eclipse documentation on managing those settings:  [Eclipse C/C++ Build](http://help.eclipse.org/indigo/index.jsp?nav=/11_4_7_0_3)